# Does every Abelian variety have a finite resolution by Jacobians?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

One knows that every Abelian variety is a quotient of a Jacobian. Does every Abelian variety have a *finite* resolution by Jacobians?

Comment: I believe this is still open, although I would also be interested
in the precise status. 

Comment: Do you have a specific motivation for this question ? For instance, are there examples of statements about abelian varieties that could be reduced to jacobians in this way ?